# Show http Json response in a DBGRID component in Delphi

Tags: json, http, delphi, delphi-2010

I am trying to populate a Dbgrid component with a Json response at runtime to display the result as a list, but I have not been able to perform this process, I added a ClientDataSet and DataSource component, I am not very knowledgeable in delphi.

```
   procedure TFConsultas.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
   URI:string;
   sResponse: string;
   codigo: string;
   I: Integer;
   Datos: TJSONValue;
   begin
    URI := 'http://localhost/E-commerce/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=';
   
    IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Accept:= 'application/json';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization:Bearer ' + FObtenerToken.token);
    try
    sResponse:=IdHTTP1.Get(URI+Edit2.Text);
    codigo:= IdHTTP1.ResponseText;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
    Memo1.Text := sResponse;
    Memo2.Text := codigo;
    Datos := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(sResponse);
```

The json is obtained correctly, the following lines of code do not know if they work correctly and can create the rows and assign the values ​​of the Json, as I mentioned I do not know much about delphi, I tried to relate the components by code and in the design properties but at the execute the form the dbgrid component is shown empty, someone could help me and mention that I am performing badly or that I am missing or the way I should do it please

```
   for I := 0 to ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do
   begin
     case ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].DataType of
   ftString, ftWideString, ftMemo :
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByName(ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].Name).AsString :=
        Datos.TryGetValue(ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].Name,Datos).ToString;

    end;
  ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftWord, ftLongWord, ftShortint :
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByName(ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].Name).AsInteger :=
        (Datos.GetValue(ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].Name,Datos) as TJsonNumber).AsInt;
    end;
  ftFloat, ftCurrency :
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByName(ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].Name).AsFloat :=
        (Datos.GetValue(ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs[I].Name,Datos) as TJsonNumber).AsDouble;
    end;
 end;
      ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
      DataSource1.DataSet:=ClientDataSet1;
      DBGrid1.DataSource:=DataSource1;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Better to ask in English if you want more people to answer. You can edit your question. Click the edit link just below it.

Comment: Actually, I don't think non-English questions are allowed at all. However, it seems like you are writing in Spanish, and so you can use the Spanish Stack Overflow: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not written in English.